# Inserting all combinations of characters into a string in Java

Tags: java, loops, math, iteration

I want to go through these two lists:
`int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`
and:
`String[] signs = {"+", "-", "/", "*", "^"}`

and produce outputs like: `1 + 2 - 3 * 4 + 5` and so on with every posible combination, maintaining the same order, but nesting the loops doesn't work either way round, so I can't think of any way of doing this. I also eventually want to be evaluating the results, but for now my aim is just to print the combinations.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to ask a specific question to get an answer. People isn't here to solve the whole problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assumptions

1. unary `-` is not considered
2. result will returned as string. postfix conversion is needed to evaluate

### Solution

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Combination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {1, 2, 3};
        String[] signs = {"+", "-", "*"};
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        results.add(String.valueOf(nums[0]));
        for (int index = 1; index < nums.length; index++) {
            final int num = nums[index];
            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (final String sign : signs) {
                for (String result : results) {
                    temp.add(result + sign + num);
                }
            }
            results = temp;
        }
        System.out.println(results);
    }
}
```

### Alternate suggestion

Analyzing this problem as a `graph` problem will help us propose a basic version of the solution

- The first number can be thought of as the root node
- Add one edge per sign from this node to next number (another node)
- Move to the new node and repeatedly add different edges to the next node.
- Then do a DFS traversal from root and record all the paths from root to leaf.

Comment: Are there any advantages of using DFS compared to BFS for this?

Comment: And also, are there advantages of treating it as a graph?

Comment: @OctopuSS7, The advantage of treating it as a graph problem is, its easy to visualize about construction and traversal techniques. 1. Construct the graph using a level order traversal. Add first node as root. Add second node to next level and add all possible edges from first node to second. Add third node in next level and add add all possible edges from second to third. continue similarly. 2. DFS traversal is the natural technique for the above constructed graph as we need each possible complete expression and DFS will exactly do that. BFS/level order(similar to my code) is not intuitive.